# Trendline 30 days interval - month repeated in labels

Tags: sql-server, sql-function, trendline

Use the below query to check the 30 day interval for the trendline. But the problem is **IT RESULTS THE REPEATED MONTHS ANY SOLUTION**

```
USE [Database];
DECLARE @toDate NVARCHAR(30)  = '2020-05-29';
DECLARE @T table(ID int, toDate date, fromDate date, xVal NVARCHAR(100), indexVal NVARCHAR(100))
    insert into @T values(1, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-30) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(2, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-30) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-60) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(3, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-60) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-90) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(4, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-90) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-120) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(5, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-120) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-150) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(6, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-150) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-180) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(7, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-180) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-210) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(8, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-210) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-240) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(9, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-240) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-270) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(10, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-270) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-300) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(11, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-300) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-330) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(12, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-330) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-360) as date),'',0)

    UPDATE @T SET 
        xVal = CONCAT(FORMAT(toDate , 'MMM'), '-', YEAR(toDate))
    select * from @T as T
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us the result that you want, as tabular text.

Comment: I need to split the labels by month wise it should go on the intervals as 30 days.

Not as repeated one as below in the result
May
Apr
Mar
Feb
Jan
Dec
Nov
Oct
Sep
Aug
Jul

@GMB

Answer (score 1):

Check out the below one **but it will have defect too that specifies wrong date for wrong month**

```
USE [database];
DECLARE @toDate NVARCHAR(30)  = '2020-03-01';
DECLARE @T table(ID int, toDate date, fromDate date, xVal NVARCHAR(100), indexVal NVARCHAR(100))
    insert into @T values(1, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-30) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(2, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-30) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-60) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(3, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-60) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-90) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(4, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-90) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-120) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(5, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-120) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-150) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(6, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-150) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-180) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(7, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-180) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-210) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(8, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-210) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-240) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(9, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-240) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-270) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(10, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-270) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-300) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(11, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-300) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-330) as date),'',0)
    insert into @T values(12, Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-330) as date), Cast((select (Cast(@toDate as datetime))-360) as date),'',0)
    UPDATE @T SET 
        xVal = CONCAT(FORMAT(DateAdd(month,-(ID-1),@todate) , 'MMM'), '-', YEAR(DateAdd(month,-(ID-1),@todate)))
    select * from @T as T
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to generate a series of start and end of months. Months have varying number of days, so you want to offset by month, not by days.

I would recommend:

```
declare @toDate NVARCHAR(30)  = '2020-05-01'; -- beginning of the month
declare @T table(ID int, toDate date, fromDate date, xVal NVARCHAR(100), indexVal NVARCHAR(100));

insert into @T(ID, fromDate, toDate) values
    (1, @toDate, emonth(@toDate),
    (2, dateadd(month, -1, @toDate), emonth(dateadd(month, -1, @toDate)),
    (3, dateadd(month, -2, @toDate), emonth(dateadd(month, -2, @toDate)),
    (4, dateadd(month, -3, @toDate), emonth(dateadd(month, -3, @toDate)),
    ...
```

Comment: But again it comes under the month interval and not the 30 days interval it will void the function/feature needed.

For your info, it will start as any date @toDate

Comment: @Rishi: just replace `@toDate` with `datefromparts(year(@toDate), month(@toDate), 1)`

Comment: But it wont satisfy the @todate  as current date and last 30 days from now

It will go through the todate as the start of the month always in every month